# Fundamental group of the space $\Bbb CP^n-p(X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $p : \Bbb C^{n+1} \to \Bbb CP^n$ be the standard quotient map, let $X=\{(z_0, ..., z_n ) \in \Bbb C^{n+1} ~|~ z_0^2 + ... +z_n^2=0 \}$, and consider the space $p(X)$. I want to compute the fundamental group of the space $\Bbb CP^n-p(X)$. To do this, I first want to know how does the space $p(X)$ look like, but I have no idea. Any hints?

Comment: What is the standard quotient map $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$?  Do you mean $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}-\{0\}$?

Comment: @Connor Malin Yes, my mistake

Comment: What is the fundamental group of $\Bbb{C}^2 - \{ z_1=0\}$ ? It should work quite the same way for the fundamental group of $\Bbb{C}^2 - \{1+ z_1^2+z_2^2=0\}$ the affine part of $\Bbb{C}P^2 -p(\{ z_0^2+z_1^2+z_2^2=0\}) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider $V:=\{(z_0,\ldots,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}:z_0^2+\cdots+z_n^2=1\}$ and verify that the standard projection restricted to $V$ becomes a 2-sheeted covering map (actually it is sufficient to notice that $p\mid_V$ is a quotient map, but in this particular case it can be easily seen by noticing that $V$ is a cover).

To be specific, let an arbitary point $[z_0:\cdots:z_n]\in\mathbb{C}P^n$ be given. WLOG assume $z_0=1$. For sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$,

$\qquad U_\epsilon:=\{\,[1:w_1:\cdots:w_n]:(w_1,\ldots,w_n)\,\text{is in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of}\,(z_1,\ldots,z_n)\,\text{in}\,\mathbb{C}^n.\}$

is a well-defined neighborhood of $[1:z_1:\cdots:z_n]$ both in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ and $\mathbb{C}P^n-p(X)$. Then $(p\mid_V)^{-1}(U_\epsilon)$ has two connected components $\widetilde{U_\epsilon}^{(1)}$ and $\,\widetilde{U_\epsilon}^{(2)}=-\widetilde{U_\epsilon}^{(1)}$ that evenly cover $U_\epsilon$, again provided that you chose sufficiently small $\epsilon$ (Check this by constructing explicit homeomorphisms from $U_\epsilon$ to its sheets!).

Now you can understand $\mathbb{C}P^n-p(X)$ via its cover $V$. Embed $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2(n+1)}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ to see that

$\qquad V=\{(\vec{x},\vec{y})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}: |\vec{x}|^2=|\vec{y}|^2+1\quad\text{and}\quad\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=0\}$.

Construct an explicit homeomorphism from $V$ to

$\qquad TS^{n}=\{(\vec{x}',\vec{y}')\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:|\vec{x}'|^2=1\quad \text{and}\quad \vec{x}'\cdot\vec{y}'=0\}$, the tangent bundle over $S^{n}$.

Since you're looking for the fundamental group, you can deformation retract $TS^{n}$ into an even simpler space, namely $S^{n}$; just send every tangent vector $\vec{y}'$ to $(1-t)\vec{y}'$ as $t\in [0,1]$.

To mimic $\,\mathbb{C}P^n-p(X)\,$ we shall quotient $TS^{n}$ and $S^{n}$ by the identification

$\qquad\mathbf{v}\sim\mathbf{-v}\quad\text{for every}\,\mathbf{v}.$

Observe that $\mathbb{C}P^n-p(X)\simeq TS^{n}/_{\sim}$ since they are quotients obtained from homeomorphic spaces by identifying (essentially) same sets of points.

The deformation retraction $TS^{n}\rightarrow S^{n}$ suggests our final deformation retraction

$\qquad TS^{n}/_{\sim}\rightarrow S^{n}/_{\sim}\simeq\mathbb{R}P^n$.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    V @>\simeq>> TS^{n} @>d.r.>> S^n\\
    @V p VV @VV quot. V @VV quot. V\\
    \mathbb{C}P^n-p(X) @>>\simeq> TS^{n}/_{\sim} @>d.r.>>\mathbb{R}P^n
\end{CD}

('d.r.' for deformation retractions, 'quot.' for quotient maps)

As it turns out, the fundamental group of $\;\mathbb{C}P^n-p(X)\;$ is that of $\;\mathbb{R}P^n\;$, to wit: $\mathbb{Z}\;(n=1), \mathbb{Z}_2\;(n\geq 2)$.

Comment: Can you give more details about showing that $p|_V$ is a covering map? I understood all the other steps except this part.

Comment: To show $p\mid_V$ is a cover, it is enough to show that arbitrarily give point has an evenly covered neighborhood. I constructed a suitable neighborhood $U_\epsilon$ and it's pre-image. That the components homeomorphically project onto $U_\epsilon$ can be seen from the following map: $[1:z_1:\cdots:z_n]\mapsto\frac{1}{1+z_1^2+\cdots+z_n^2}(1,z_1,\ldots,z_n) $ i.e. this is the local inverse of $p\mid_V$. (What should the other map be?)

Comment: In fact, that you can choose suitable $\epsilon>0$ for $\widetilde{U_\epsilon}^{(1),(2)}$ to be disjoint and homeomorphic to $U_\epsilon$ is a direct consequence of such map.

Comment: Why is that local inverse is continuous? It seems not trivial to me because the domain is a quotient space

Comment: Because $\phi_0:U_0\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n:[1:z_1:\cdots:z_n]\mapsto(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ is a homeomorphism. Here $U_0=\{[z_0:\cdots:z_n]\in\mathbb{C}P^n:z_0\neq0\}=\{[1:z_1:\cdots:z_n]\in\mathbb{C}P^n:z_1,\ldots,z_n\in\mathbb{C}\}$. That $\phi_0$ is continuous can be seen by using the characteristic property of quotient map. Continuous inverse of $\phi_0$ can be written in an obvious way.

Comment: Okay. But don't we have to take the local inverse as $[1:z_1 : ...  :z_n] \mapsto $ ${1} \over (1+z_1^2+...+z_n^2)^{1/2}$ $(1,z_1,...,z_n)$?

Comment: Yes! But that is just the composition of $\phi_0$ with a continuous map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $V$. What I did is to give $\mathbb{C}P^n$ a local coordinate system, for which $\phi_0$ stands, to make an abstract space(which is defined via quotient) understandable(it is locally homeomorphic to complex Euclidean space!).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99263/discussion-between-hyeongmuk-lim-and-comol).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to do this with algebra, but the space is diffeomorphic to the tangent bundle on $\mathbb RP^n$ (see my question and the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866337/mathbb-cpn-with-a-quadric-removed-is-homeomorphic-to-t-mathbb-rpn)), and hence homotopic to $\mathbb RP^n$, so its fundamental group is $\mathbb Z/2$.

For a different approach: I think the suggestion in the comments is also good, since for a manifold of dimension at least three, you can remove a point from  your space, and pass to affine coordinates, solving the questiion there (since the fundamental group will be unchanged, which is proven by seifert van kampen.)

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't learn about tangent bundles. Are there some good references to learn about tangent bundles?

Comment: I don't think that this is the most important point here.  Maybe just read the constructioin, and note that there is a relationshiip between $S^n$ and vectors tangent to it and $S^n$, namely that  the former deformation retracts onto $S^n$ by the contractibility of each tangent space.