# Fundamental Group of $\mathbb{R}^n$ subtracted by a star-shaped domain

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

everyone! I'm a physics PhD student who knows little about algebraic topology. Recently I encountered a problem about the topology of the manifold $$M:=\left\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3 \mid z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2\neq 0 \right\}. $$ where I need to calculate the fundamental group of $M$.

My first step is to consider the compliment set $$\overline{M}=\left\{ (z_1,z_2,z_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3\mid z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2= 0 \right\}. $$ Because the equation $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2= 0$ is a homogeneous equation, the set $\overline{M}$ is a [star-shaped set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain).

Next, I change the complex variables to the real ones, i.e.
\begin{align*}
z_1 &= x_1 + iy_1 \\
z_2 &= x_2 + iy_2 \\
z_3 &= x_3 + iy_3 \\
\end{align*}
and the complex equation $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2= 0$ is equivalent to the real system of equations
\begin{align}
\left(x_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{3}\right)^{2} & =\left(y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(y_{2}\right)^{2}+\left(y_{3}\right)^{2} \label{eq1}\\
x_{1}y_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}+x_{3}y_{3} & =0 \label{eq2}
\end{align}

Because the set $\overline{M}$ is a star-shaped set, I can move the point in $M$ along the rays started from the origin to the unit sphere $S^5$, so that $M$ is homotopic equivalent to $S^5 - \overline{M}\cap S^5$. Next, I consider the two real vectors $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. When the 6-vector $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ is restricted on $S^5$, the 3-vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are restricted on $S^2$ respectively, and an additional restriction $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y}=0$ is required, which restricts $\mathbf{y}$ on the equator perpendicular to $\mathbb{x}$. Therefore, the set $\overline{M}\cap S^5$ is locally homeomorphic to $S^2\times U(1)$, which means that it is an $U(1)$-principal bundle on $S^2$, or the bundle of all the unit tangent vectors of a 2D sphere. However, I don't know whether it is globally homeomorphic to $S^2\times U(1) $. Then, I'm stuck because I don't know how to calculate the fundamental group of this guy.

My questions are the followings:

1. Are there any general methods or theorems that deal with the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^n$ subtracted by a star-shaped domain?
2. If not, are there any methods to solve my problem, that is, the fundamental group of $S^5$ substracted by the bundle of the unit tangent vectors on $S^2$?

Maybe the problem is similar to [the fundamental group of $S^3-S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602825/the-fundamental-group-of-s3-s1) ?

Comment: maybe related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365744/fundamental-group-of-the-space-bbb-cpn-px (and hence your space has fundamental group 0 or $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I need.

Comment: NP. Since your space is a complex line bundle of the space $p(M)$ in the linked quotient, it seems that $M$ and $p(M)$ are homotopic equivalent  and hence the fundamental group of $M$ is $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ too.

Comment: My argument seems to be wrong.